# Batch headers are not considered for individual requests with Cloud sdk 3.66

Tags: sap-cloud-sdk

Ours is a dwc based application Master Data Proxy Service (MDPS).

We are getting an error due to the required Dwc headers (dwc-tenant, dwc-subdomain, dwc-jwt) etc,
not being propagated to **individual request contexts** from a batch request.

I did some debugging on this and here are my observations:

We create a destination with DwcHeaderProvider as header provider with the following code:

```
DefaultHttpDestination.builder(megacliteUri + MEGACLITE_VERSION + serviceBinding)
            .keyStore(dwcUtil.getKeyStore())
            .keyStorePassword("changeit")
            .proxyType(ProxyType.INTERNET)
            .headerProviders(new DwcHeaderProvider()
            // The destination that Megaclite should use to perform the request
            .header(Constants.DESTINATION_NAME, Constants.DEFAULT_DESTINATION_VALUE)
            .build();
```

**DwcHeaderProvider** in turns gets all the relevant headers including the dwc headers. But with the new version its not happening.

I can see that internally the headers are fetched from a headerFacade, which in the previous versions used to be **DefaultRequestHeaderFacade**.
Now the facade is getting initialized as com.sap.cds.integration.cloudsdk.facade.**CdsRequestHeaderFacade** and this comes from a jar
com/sap/cds/cds-integration-cloud-sdk/1.23.0/cds-integration-cloud-sdk-1.23.0.jar

**cds-integration-cloud-sdk-1.23.0.jar**

Can you look into it this? It is a high prio issue for us, since batch requests are completely not working, and our UI relies on such requests.

Thanks,
Sachin

Comment: We are currently investigating this issue. In the meanwhile, can you try whether downgrading the SAP Cloud SDK version back to `3.65.0` circumvents the issue?

Comment: No... Same behavior with that version as well.

Comment: As a temporary fix we have downgraded the cds versions to <cds.services.version>1.22.1</cds.services.version>
<cds4j.version>1.26.0</cds4j.version> With this versions it is working.

Comment: That's a very valuable input for our investigation! Thanks for letting us know.
Am I right to assume that your application is also working with the latest Cloud SDK version (`3.66.0`) when you're using the downgraded CDS version?

Comment: Yes that is right. With 3.66 version of CSDK and the above mentioned lower versions of CAP its working,

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.
We are currently reaching out to the CAP colleagues to further narrow down the source of this issue. We'll keep you posted.

Comment: A problem within the CAP/CDS header handling was identified. A fix will be released soon by them. We'll answer as soon as it's available.

Comment: CAP team confirmed that the fix would be available in their version `1.24.0` which should be available end of April '22.

Comment: FYI: Version 1.24 is released now and contains the fix :)

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** Please use CAP 1.24 - the issue is fixed already.

---

Until the problem is solved and a proper fix is released, can you try a workaround?

Before instantiating the destination run the following code snippet:

```java
import com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.requestheader.RequestHeaderAccessor;
import com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.requestheader.DefaultRequestHeaderFacade;

RequestHeaderAccessor.setHeaderFacade(new DefaultRequestHeaderFacade());
```